# Windows application which allows only a specific application to run

Tags: c#, java, .net, windows-7

I have to create an application that should run on Windows XP (SP*) & Windows 7. When the application is started, it should block all the other applications on windows & run a specific set of services/applications.

I am confused on what should be the programming language used for this app as well as how to proceed after selecting the environment.

Thanx in Advance!!

Comment: and why would you want do that?(except for hacking)

Comment: No no. I have to create an application for my client who has users working from remote places. So to keep sincerity with work, he wants such a setup. So we will actually tell the user to install the application on their system. This doesn't sound like hacking. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the OS is going to stop you from doing this.  Applications shouldn't really interfere with others.  You might consider taking a look at running the system in Kiosk Mode, which gives you what I think you're asking for.

Check out this link:
http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/DF357CDA59091AE6862576CF005EE86B

Comment: Great...I want a similar system to be built; but automated by installation of a software. So I don't want to go to each users machine to change these settings. Instead create a single executable file that would do all these steps.

Comment: You could create a Group Policy to do this.  Add each user you want into the group, and force deploy the software.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102

Answer (score 0):

if you not want to run any type of software's on your system, try to make admin in every system and keep a password to admin user, then no one able to install any new software's in your system, to monitor the system activities try to make tracking software's to remote services.

To switch a Terminal Services server into Execute mode, follow these steps:

```
Click Start, and then click Run.
In the Open box, type cmd, and then click OK.
At the command prompt, type change user /iexecute, and then press ENTER. The following message appears:
User session is ready to install applications.
Type exit, and then press ENTER.
```

When you install programs in Install mode, Terminal Services tracks all registry entries, and the HKEY_CURRENT_USER information is primarily written to the following registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Terminal Server\Install

When you finish the program installation, by clicking Finish or by typing change user /execute, the system returns to Execute mode. The registry information that was written to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry hive during installation is written to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry hive for each user when they log on to the Terminal Server.

If you installed a program before you added the Terminal Services role, the system was not "listening" to the registry writes of the installation and the registry entries were not written to the correct user registry keys. Therefore, you must reinstall the program in Install mode for the program work properly.